# SIP Server Installation in Linux

Tags: linux, fedora

[CLick Here for Kamailio Sip proxy server installation page](http://www.kamailio.org/dokuwiki/doku.php/install:openser-from-svn)

I am not able to get Prerequisites , where to download these files ? even if i get how to install the kamailio server where i getting some Errors like below : 

if i type"make all" It gives Error :
[image: make all error]
if i type "make Q=0 all" it gives error :
[image: make Q=0 all error]

Can anyone help me to fix the error n make my kamailio install proper .
Thanks in advance :)

Answered People will get Appreciation for sure .:)

Comment: Yuck! Please don't post screenshots unless unavoidable (e.g. when your system won't boot, it's ok to post a screen photo). Text on screenshots is difficult to read and not searchable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have not installed a mysql-devel package...

Comment: I installed Mysql-Devel package already

Comment: In your screenshot you have errors like `implicit declaration of function 'mysql_insert_id'`. It's mean, that compiler have missed a header file with declaration of this function... By the way: why you don't use a RPMS for Fedora - http://www.kamailio.org/dokuwiki/doku.php/packages:rpms ?